# Why is this code snippet not working? (Uwp app content to play a media content)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, assets

This is my code, I took it from an example from MSDN forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ddb1b7f1-e988-40c7-8e1e-eaf6d8573ec2/uwp-how-to-play-sound-from-wav-fileresource?forum=wpdevelop).

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;
        private TimeSpan myTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(Object sender, object e)
        {

            if (myTime.Seconds > 0)
            {
                myTime -= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                MainTextBlock.Text = myTime.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Stop();
                MainTextBlock.Text = "Finished";
                PlaySound_Async();
            }
        }

        private async void PlaySound_Async()
        {
            MediaElement timesup = new MediaElement();
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("timesup.mp3");
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            timesup.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            timesup.Play();
        }
```

And this is the exception I get this exception
I have already added the file in the right folder
[image: Assets folder]

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding files to the `Assets` folder in **File Explorer** is not a complete step of importing file into the project.  You also need to add the file to the `Assets` in the **Solution Explorer** of **Visual Studio**. You can check the following steps to import the file:

1. Click `Show All Files` option in the **Solution Explorer**, and find the `timesup.mp3` file in the `Assets` folder.

[image: Solution Explorer]

2. Right click the `timesup.mp3` file and select the `Include In Project` option.

[image: Context Menu]

3. Click the `timesup.mp3` file and ensure the `Build Action` is set to `Content` in the **Properties** window.

[image: Properties window]

In addition to using the above steps to import a file to `Assets`, you can also right-click `Assets` and select **Add> Existing item…**, select the target file and click `Add` button to import a file.

Furthermore, if you want to know how to look at the output of the folder variable, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#inspect-variables-with-data-tips).

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint on GetFolderAsync, you should be able to look at the folder variable and see where it thinks the Path is... is it the same absolute path that you expect it to be (C:\Users....repos\Multi-timer)